# requests_mock multiple responses for single url

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest, requests-mock

I am trying to use the requests_mock as part of my unit test to test API Calls which run in a while loop so in order to end the while loop or to meet the condition of the while loop I need to send different response to my API. **My URL remains the same** but the param changes but *requests_mock* doesn't really cares about it.

My function goes like this :

```
def func():    
   response = requests.get(
       url=<url>
       params={"limit": 1000}
       headers=<headers>
    ).json()
    while "next" in response["info"].keys():
        response =  requests.get(
            url=<url>
            params={"limit": 1000, "info": response["info"]}
            headers=<headers>
        ).json()
```

My test looks like:

```
def test_url(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.get(url, json=<response_with_info_key>)

    func()
    data_request = requests_mock.request_history[0]
    assert data_request.query = "limit=1000"
```

What i want is my while loop to end with my second response to be without the "next" key. What I have already tried :

```
def test_url(requests_mock):
    requests_mock.get(url, json=[<response_with_info_key>, <response_without_info_key>])

    func()
    data_request = requests_mock.request_history[0]
    assert data_request.query = "limit=1000"
```

The simplest way to explain the whole question would be : **How do i make requests-mock send two different response for the same API?**

Comment: please show how you are setting up your requests_mock object

Comment: I use the default setting and I import the requests_mock as part of my test function as shown in the test. Then I use it to mock my request API

Comment: you need to configure it to return a list as shown --> https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#response-lists

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't very clear on how to go about this, and after breaking my head for a while I was able to put together [this article](https://medium.com/python-in-plain-english/additional-custom-matchers-for-requests-mock-mocking-in-python-2ae13847f32c) explaining how custom matchers for `requests_mock` work.

In a nutshell: if you want your mocked API to return different responses based on the requests (headers, content, querystrings, whatever) you will need to register the URL multiple times with custom matchers and responses based on those matchers.

A custom matcher simply returns whether the request matched or not, you can even configure a single matcher to check for multiple URLs based on the URL in the request being matched.

The sample I created will hopefully make it clear enough for your use case:

```
from http import HTTPStatus
import requests
import requests_mock

def a_matcher(request):
    data = request.json().get("data", {})
    if "a" in data.keys():
        return True
    return None

def b_matcher(request):
    data = request.json().get("data", {})
    if "b" in data.keys():
        return True
    return None

def test_calls_made_out_of_order():
    status_code_a = int(HTTPStatus.OK)
    status_code_b = int(HTTPStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mocker:
        mocker.post(
            "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic",
            additional_matcher=a_matcher,
            status_code=status_code_a
        )

        mocker.post(
            "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic",
            additional_matcher=b_matcher,
            status_code=status_code_b
        )

        response_b = requests.post(
            "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic",
            headers={
              "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            json={
                "data": {
                    "b": True,
                }
            },
        )

        assert response_b.status_code == status_code_b

        response_a = requests.post(
            "http://www.example.com/path/to/the/magic",
            headers={
              "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            json={
                "data": {
                    "a": True,
                }
            },
        )

        assert response_a.status_code == status_code_a
```